# New to iis 8.5, error 404

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, iis-8

I have just started using IIS 8, and saw a tutorial that says to put a webpage under the root folder, and try to enter the URL to see if it works. So, I added a web page called default.html under the wwwroot folder, and try to access the URL http://localhost/default.html and I either get "404 error. page not found." I have tried various links but none seem to work.

Can you suggest a possible solution to this?

Also, I am very new to IIS, so I would appreciate it if you could give a lot of detail.

Thank you.

Update:
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqjhC.jpg)

Comment: On the file add the read permission to "users" group

Comment: @bdn02, I gave "Full Control" to everyone listed for that file, which includes, "SYSTEM", "Administrators", "Users", "IIS_IUSRS", and "TrustedInstallers". Any other suggestions? Also, I checked off the box that says "Read-Only" in the "General" tab.

Comment: Open iis management console, check that the website is started, that the port is 80 and that the default websiste point to c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder

Comment: yep, all of those are confirmed

Comment: Can you look into the today log file in directory C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1

Comment: my C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles folder is empty. Also, I can't find the folder that you have specified, this is the only one under logs.

Comment: Very strange. If you open the http://localhost/ url you can view the initial page of iis8?

Comment: I deleted that earlier, because I was following a tutorial and they said to delete it. I did not try opening that page.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of error page?

Comment: I want to view the module, handler, requested and phisical path. One question: on your computer you have installed skype?